# adb shelll setprop failing with max 2 arguments

Tags: android, adb

I am running the following command wrap my application with valgrind

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.mycompany.syam.simplecalc "logwrapper /data/local/start_valgrind.sh"
```

But it is failing with following error

```
setprop: Max 2 arguments
```

Anybody help me understand why am I getting this error? Isn't it supporting strings inside double quotes? And what is the fix for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983617/1778421

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.mycompany.syam.simplecalc "logwrapper' '/data/local/start_valgrind.sh"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain why/how your answer works

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused by space problem so this is your fixed answer:

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.mycompany.syam.simplecalc "logwrapper/data/local/start_valgrind.sh"
```

Hope that helps