# How do I Replace a File in the Internal Storage of a Debuggable App?

Tags: android, adb

I've got an android app, which is debuggable.

I can back up its important files to my PC like so:

```
adb exec-out run-as org.test.myapp cat files/afile > afile-from-phone
```

But how do I put them back?

I.e. what command with copy the file

**afile-from-phone**

from my pc to

**files/afile**

in the storage area that belongs to org.test.myapp on the phone?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22703254/1778421

Answer (score 0):

If your device allows you to run adb as root you can do:

`adb push afile-from-phone data/app/org.test.myapp/`

Change "data" for "system" if it's a system app.